# Case classes matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I want to have this comparison function that matches two case classes, but it's a bit verbose.

Leafs are always in the sorted order in the List.

```
  abstract class CodeTree
  case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree
  case class Leaf(char: Char, weight: Int) extends CodeTree

  def sortCodeTreeFun(x: CodeTree, y: CodeTree) = {
    (x, y) match {
      case (x1: Leaf, y1: Leaf) => true
      case (x1: Fork, y1: Leaf) => x1.weight < y1.weight
      case (x1: Leaf, y1: Fork) => x1.weight < y1.weight
      case (x1: Fork, y1: Fork) => x1.weight < y1.weight
    }
  }
```

I tried to modify CodeTree constructor to be:

```
  abstract class CodeTree(weight: Int)
```

So that I can compare x and y directly, but compiler says:

> "not enough arguments for constructor CodeTree: (weight: Int)patmat.Huffman.CodeTree"

Is there another way to shorten sortCodeTreeFun method?

Comment: This is homework from the FP in Scala online course

Comment: pure violation of honor code 4 with course conductors of "Functional programing in scala"
"I will not try to dishonestly improve my code...."

Comment: I've already completed the assignment and got 10/10. Don't see anything dishonorable in trying to improve my understanding of the Scala language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply say:

```
def sortCodeTreeFun(x: CodeTree, y: CodeTree) = {
  (x, y) match {
    case (_: Leaf, _: Leaf)           => true
    case (x1: CodeTree, y1: CodeTree) => x1.weight < y1.weight
  }
}
```

And define abstract class CodeTree as

```
abstract class CodeTree {
  def weight: Int
}
```

The reason for the error is that when you extend an class that take a parameter you need to supply the parameter. So for

```
abstract class CodeTree(weight: Int)
```

You need to extend it as

```
case class Fork(left: CodeTree, right: CodeTree, chars: List[Char], weight: Int) extends CodeTree(weight)
```

That's what the error you were getting was saying:

```
"not enough arguments for constructor CodeTree: (weight: Int)"
```

It was because you weren't supplying the required argument `weight` when extending CodeTree.

The problem with this approach though is that weight is not a member of CodeTree and hence can not to be accessed from an instance of type CodeTree. That is to say, if you did:

```
 scala> Fork(...).asInstanceOf[CodeTree].weight
 <console>:11: error: value weight is not a member of CodeTree
```

So, in your pattern match, you wouldn't be able to do `x1.weight` since the type of x1 is a `CodeTree` and `CodeTree` does not have a `weight`.

Comment: Great, thanks! But could you please explain why I was getting an error I was getting?

Comment: Because you didn't provide the weight to the CodeTree when you extend it.

Comment: What @Victor Klag said. Edited to include the reason for the error. Might have gone a little long-winded with it though :).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort elements like codetrees, you can use 
[`Sorting.stableSort`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Sorting%24.html)