# Can I use abstract types in matching of case classes?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

Or, in other words:
Can I verify with matching if elements in a tuple are of the same case class, despite having different values in theirs fields (arguments)?
Is there something equivalent to the **case[T]** below?

```
sealed abstract class RootClass
case class ChildClassX(valuex: Boolean) extends RootClass
case class ChildClassY(valuey: Boolean) extends RootClass
// and other case classes here...

object Foo {
def compare(a: RootClass, b: RootClass) = {
    (a, b) match {
       case[T] (T(a), T(b)) => a == b
       case _ => throw Exception("a and b should be of same child classes.")
    }
}
```

I hope I dont have to do:

```
object Foo {
def compare(a: RootClass, b: RootClass) = {
    (a, b) match {
       case (ChildClassX(a), ChildClassX(b)) | (ChildClassY(a), ChildClassY(b)) | (ChildClassZ(a), ChildClassZ(b)) | etc. => a == b
       case _ => throw Exception("a and b should be of same child classes.")
    }
}
```

Related:
[matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039472/case-classes-matching-in-scala)

Comment: Why not just define `compare` in `Foo` as: `def compare(a: RootClass, b: RootClass) = a == b`? And let the caller handle the check for types if it returns false. Seems more inline with what to expect from a compare function?

Comment: Good point, but I called it misleading here as "compare". In reality it is an "eval" that descends a tree of case classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reasonable solution that I can think of is to simply compare the two items' classes.

```
(a, b) match {
  case (x,y) if x.getClass == y.getClass => "matching classes"
  case _ => "no match"
}
```

I am not aware of any construct that works the way you describe, like `case[T]`.

Comment: Better than my present code with isInstanceOfs or lot of cases :)

Comment: One thing you'll have to be aware of if you use this approach is subclasses: `class A; class B extends A; val a1: A = new A; val a2: A = new B; a1.getClass != a2.getClass` - even though they technically are both instances of `A`, `getClass` will return the *instance's* class, which would mess things up in this approach.

Comment: that's ok, it is the behavior I need.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution, I guess - if it's really only about the classes:

```
object Foo {
  def compare[A,B](a: A, b: B) =
    if (a.getClass.getSuperclass != b.getClass.getSuperclass)
      throw new MatchError("a and b should be of same child classes.")
    else (a.getClass == b.getClass)
}
```

No matching involved... Maybe someone has a more elegant solution? But this is maybe the shortest...

Example test code:

```
object ObjCmp extends App {
  case object X
  val p: Product = ChildClassX(true)
  println(Foo.compare(ChildClassX(true), ChildClassX(false)))
  println(Foo.compare(ChildClassX(true), ChildClassY(false)))
  println(Foo.compare(ChildClassX(true), p))
  println(Foo.compare(ChildClassX(true), X))
}
```

prints:

```
true
false
true
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: a and b should be of same child classes.
```